# Find all solutions of the equation $[6]x = [12]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that the solution for $x$ is $18k + 5$ for all integers $k$ because I can figure that out in my head. But is there a specific method for solving these types of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Write $6x \equiv 12 \bmod 18$ as

$$6x - 18y = 12$$

where $x$ and $y$ are integer variables.  Since $\gcd(6,18) = 6 \mid 12$, there are solutions of this equation.  Divide both sides by $6$ to get

$$x - 3y = 2$$

Now, determine the set of integer solutions for $x$ that belong to $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$.

Comment: So if I do it in the way you suggest, I get that x=2+3y for all integers y. Is the solution I posed (x=18k + 5 for all integers k) incorrect?

Comment: If $x = 2$, this works.  So $x = 18k + 5$ is not a 'complete' solution.

Comment: I see, so 18k+5 is included in the solution, but is not the entire solution

Comment: Where do you claim to have used FTA?

Comment: Fixed my answer a bit.  Maybe, my answer misses few points or so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general result for equations of the form $ax\equiv b (\mod m)$, with $a,b\in Z$ and $a\neq 0$ :
The congruence $ax\equiv b (\mod m)$ has a solution if and only if $(a,m)$ divides $b$. In this case the congruence has $(a,m)$ distinct solutions, i.e., solutions in distinct congruence classes $(\mod m)$.
(If there is a solution $x$, then all members of the congruence class of $x$ are also solutions.)
If you are unable to find this result, let me know. I have written a proof of it and examples of its application, which I can send you (but it may take a little time).